# Python serialization issue

Tags: python, serialization

I am getting a json message/event with messed up types like:

```
{
    "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
      "UnusedAccountValidityDays": "7",
      "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": "true"
    }
    ...
}
```

I figured out that the best way is to serialize and deserialize using a custom serializer

code:

```
event = json.loads( json.dumps(event, mySerializer) )

def mySerializer(o):
    if isinstance(o, unicode): 
        if o in ["true", "True"]: return True
        elif o in ["false", "False"]: return False
        else: 
            try:
                return int(o)
            except:
                return o
    else:
        return o.__dict__
```

But my problem is that after the serialization and deserialization I still get the same strings/unicodes:

```
AdminCreateUserConfig.UnusedAccountValidityDays: 7, type: <type 'unicode'>
AdminCreateUserConfig.AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: true, type: <type 'unicode'>
```

What should I change?

TLDR: I am in AWS Lambda, and I have the json Object, this is why I need to do the conversion two more times.

Comment: Isn't your code more of a deserializer, that - if anything - should be passed to `loads` and not `dumps`?

Comment: Well actually you can do that on both ends. I thought it is more easy to say that strings must be handled differently. But it seems that this kind of override does not work for naturally serializable objects like string - or my code is ignored for some other reason.7

If I want to use my code as a deserializer (like: `event = json.loads( json.dumps(event), object_hook = mySerializer ))` )  it says. `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__dict__' `

Comment: @BTakacs see my answer for more detail, but object_hook will only translate objects (e.g. dicts), to access key value pairs of objects, you need to use object_pairs_hooks. Ultimately I prefer to use a tool like Marshmallow for this though (again, see my answer for more detail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the key-value pairs of objects as they are being decoded, you need to define an [`object_pairs_hook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) method:

```
def object_pairs_hook(pairs):
    decoded_pairs = []
    for key, val in pairs:
        # python 2/3 compatability support
        try:
            type_ = unicode
        except NameError:
            type_ = str

        if isinstance(val, type_):
            if val.lower() == "true":
                val = True
            elif val.lower() == "false":
                val = False
            else:
                try:
                    val = int(val)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        decoded_pairs.append((key, val))

    return dict(decoded_pairs)
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{ "hi": { "foo": "true", "bar": "2" } }', object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook)
{u'hi': {u'foo': True, u'bar': 2}}
```

The `object_hook` method (or providing a custom `JSONDecoder` class) will only be called for objects and will not be called for keys and values of objects.

#### Using Marshmallow

If your data is well-formed, it would be better to use a library like [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/) which already handles cases like this. To use it you would define a schema:

```
import marshmallow

class AdminCreateUserConfig(marshmallow.Schema):
    UnusedAccountValidityDays = marshmallow.fields.Int()
    AllowAdminCreateUserOnly = marshmallow.fields.Bool()

class MySchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    AdminCreateUserConfig = marshmallow.fields.Nested(AdminCreateUserConfig)
```

And then you can call loads to deserialize:

```
>>> MySchema().loads('{ "AdminCreateUserConfig": { "UnusedAccountValidityDays": "7", "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": "true" } }')
{'AdminCreateUserConfig': {'UnusedAccountValidityDays': 7, 'AllowAdminCreateUserOnly': True}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!
Marshmallow: I prefer general solution here instead of fixing/overriding all the fields manually. But I understand that there are use cases for that also :-)